# How is the variance $X_k$ calculated in this problem?

Tags: probability, variance

I am looking at this [problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417264/sum-of-a-random-number-of-r-v-s) and see that the variance $X_k$ calculated as follow:

$$\textrm{var}(X_k) = \frac{1}{12}\times 5^2 = \frac{25}{12}.$$

I don't quite get where that comes from.  Can someone explain to me?  Thanks.

Comment: I would say it’s wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's stated that $X_k$ would be uniform, but I'm not convinced that it is. Oh well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the variance of a uniform distribution. It's mentioned there that $X_k$ is uniform over the interval $[0,5]$, and therefore the variance is
$$
\text{Var}[X_k] = \frac{(5-0)^2}{12} = \frac{25}{12}
$$
In probability, the formula $\frac{1}{12}(b-a)^2$ is a reoccurring and important formula that should be memorised.

---

Note: In the context, I'm not convinced that $X_k$ actually has a uniform distribution. But in the case that we have **a uniformly distributed variable**, the variance is calculated as shown.

Comment: I think the problem is pretentious in its setup.  $X_k$ is logically discrete, but the uniform distribution assumption is forced on it to get this value.  Do you concur?